# How to check whether activity contains required fragment in container on activity test in espresso?

Tags: android, testing, android-fragments, android-activity, android-espresso

I have a situation,
my test code
**MyActivityTest.kt**
`

```
@Test
fun navigateToLoginFragment() {
    val intent =
        Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MyActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra("page", "Login")
    scenario = launchActivity(intent)
//pending : assert whether displayed fragment is LoginFragment or not
// ToDo
}
```

`

and activity,

**MyActivity.kt**
`

```
mPageMode = intent.getStringExtra("page")

when (mPageMode) {
    "Login" -> {
        MyUtility.replaceFragment(
            supportFragmentManager,
            LoginFragment()
        )
    }

    "Register" -> {
        MyUtility.replaceFragment(
            supportFragmentManager,
            RegistrationFragment()
        )
    }
```

`

I want to check whether displayed fragment on activity is LoginFragment or RegistrationFragment. How to do it in espresso testing?

I tried below code
`

```
onView(withId(R.id.fragment_container)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

`
but it can't get the exact fragment that is displayed

Comment: You can always check with some view inside the fragment that you want to check.

Comment: @robigroza For now, I am doing the same. But I was trying to know if there are any other solution available.